# Right way to set custom dimension for custom report with ga.js

Tags: google-analytics

I've created a very basic ab testing tool for my website

Which is the right way to set the dimension? Pageview or set?

My pageview code

```
if(control){
    ga('send', 'pageview', {
        'dimension20':  'control'
    });
} else {
    ga('send', 'pageview', {
        'dimension20':  'variation'
    });
}
```

Or setting the dimension

```
if(control){
    ga('set', 'dimension20', 'control');
} else {
    ga('set', 'dimension20', 'variation');
}
```

I'm not sure sure how long google takes to update the data, but setting the dimension seems to do nothing, pageview seems to work in my custom report but the bounce rate is very low, is sending page view affecting my bounce rate?

Bounce rate on the far right of the table when using pageview to set custom dimension, with sessions to the left of it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it by setting the dimension then sending an event, also set nonInteraction to true so it doesn't effect the bounce rate.

```
if(control){

    // if bucketed into control, set cookie so they are in control next time they load, also set ga demension that they're in control

    Cookies.set(cookieName, 'control');

    if(!internal){
        ga('set', gaDimension, testName + 'control');
        ga('send', 'event', 'InternalAB', 'ABCustom', {
            nonInteraction: true
        });
    }
} else {
    // if bucketed into variation, set cookie so they are in variation next time they load, also set ga demension that they're in variation and load the test

    Cookies.set(cookieName, 'variation');

    if(!internal){
        ga('set', gaDimension, testName + 'variation');
        ga('send', 'event', 'InternalAB', 'ABCustom', {
            nonInteraction: true
        });
    }
    load_test();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, google analytics updates the data several times a  day, so you will see results soon.
About your question: by this code

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
    'dimension20':  'control'
});
```

you're sending this dimension with only one pageview
and by setting

```
ga('set', 'dimension20', 'control');
```

you're sending this dimension with every pageview or event. So it depends of scope of your dimension which way is better.
You can try GA Debugger extension for Chrome for better understanding what's going on.

Comment: Okay I'm gonna go with just `ga('set', 'dimension20', 'control');` and see what the results look like tomorrow

Comment: But as XTOTHEL said you need to send something to GA after setting dimension this way.

Comment: So if I set the dimension then send pageview that should work?

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use set, you need to do so before sending the pageview, otherwise, the dimension won't get passed on until the next hit.

I would recommend set as the CD will be set for any other events that you might've configured on the page (clicks, pdf downloads, etc).